# Can We Dynamically Create Accept Header In External Credentials

Tags: callout, external-services, externalcredentials

We have an External Service which uses different `accept` headers based on the operation such as:

- Operation1 - application/op1+json
- Operation2 - application/op2+json
- Operation3 - application/op3+json

I am trying to understand if we can use Custom Metadata Types to dynamically create the `accept` header values? Or at least some method to do this using the declarative `External Credentials`. All of the documentation talks about using `$Credential` merge fields only. When I try the below I get

> "field [fieldName] does not exist"

So can we do something like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made it too complicated. I can just put multiple `accept` records in the header to solve this.